# SFML sockets, what does a UDP socket returning "Disconnected" mean?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, sfml

I'm writing a network program using SFML, and as my understanding was, UDP sockets are utterly connection-less

When i try read from my socket, I'm getting a "Disconnected" error code, but the documentation doesn't seem to mention UDP sockets being able to return this kind of error (only TCP ones being able to)

What could a UDP socket being Disconnected possibly mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While UDP as a protocol is "connectionless", the socket APIs support virtual connections to allow connection oriented functions to continue to work. When you call `connect` on a UDP socket, the OS remembers the connection data you set just as it normally would and it filters things that are not consistent with the virtual connection, this allows you to use interfaces like `recv`, `send` and `getpeername` because the peer is implicit. If you don't use connect, then you need to use interfaces like `sendmsg`. `sendto`, `recvmsg` and `recvfrom` where the peer is being communicated on a per packet basis.

In the case of SFML, it isn't necessarily using something that needs a connection, though, it is remapping other errors such as timeouts to [Disconnected](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/59df9d0d887f11724679f2c99dec0f05d6caeaf4/src/SFML/Network/Unix/SocketImpl.cpp#L100).